# Cellular internet coverage in Norway

Tags: cellphones, internet, norway

I am travelling to Norway for few days and need cellular data access during my stay. I am planning to buy '3' network's pay as you go card so that i can take advantage of their 'Feel at Home' facility in Norway:
http://www.three.co.uk/Discover/Phones/Feel_At_Home

Do i have any other better option? and how is cellular coverage in Norway for '3' network operator?

Comment: Where are you coming from, and what (if any) European SIM cards do you already have?

Comment: Travelling from Uk to norway. Dont have any European sim cards.

Comment: i have a mobile phone in UK with lycamobile network. No european sim cards (i didn't count UK here) :)

Comment: Did you check what they want to use your existing sim in Norwary? With the [roaming price drops in the EU on 1st July 2014](http://ec.europa.eu/digital-agenda/en/roaming-tariffs), the maximum you can be charged is €0.20/mb, and most plans are less, sometimes much less!

Answer (score 6):

Just back from trip to Norway. Used the '3' network pay as you go data card in Norway. Excellent network coverage at UK home country rates - works out to be 1p per MB. Network i was signed on to was 'N Telenor'.